# QWebView setRawHeader not working

Tags: qt, cookies, qwebview, qnetworkrequest

Currently I am trying to send a specific header through webview (Qt5), using the following piece of code. I already read about CookieJar etc but I do not need the cookies that the server return, I just need to send it and that's it.

```
    QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest();
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setRawHeader("PHPSESSID", "123123123");
    ui->webView_5->load(request);
```

but without succcess, because the custom header is not being sent to the server. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you verifying that it isn't sent to the server?

Comment: Because the session isn't being created, and i tryied with the user-agent header, but is not sent...

Comment: Again, how are you verifying that this isn't sent?

Comment: Do you want me to send you a screenshot of fiddler debugging?

Comment: It would be helpful to attach that to the question, yes.

Comment: Not enough rep to add image to the post. http://i.gyazo.com/79d91360b9707cd4e99e7472a973d0b1.png